# How to read the log file back and format it and display it in the ricjhTextBox1?

Tags: c#, winforms

What I want to do is to add in the Logger class a method that I can call in form1 that will check if the logger file exists and if the logger file size is more then 0kb and then if the logger file exists and has any content, read the logger file content and display it in the richTextBox1 in the same format it's showing it in the richTextbox1 runtime.

The problem is how to read the logger file and format the content and add it to the richTextbox1 so it will look like with the same text font size and colors as it is at runtime display in the richTextBox1.

maybe I need to track and record somehow the richTextBox1 at runtime information like font size and colors and more?

At the top of form1

```
private Logger logger;
```

In the constructor

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    logger = new Logger(richTextBox1, checkBoxSaveLogger.Checked);
}
```

Example of using it in form1

```
string endTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
logger.Log($"Ended At: {endTime}", Color.White);
```

and the Logger class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Logging
{
    public class Logger
    {
        private readonly RichTextBox _richTextBox;
        private bool saveToFile; // Added a flag to indicate whether to save to a file

        public Logger(RichTextBox richTextBox, bool saveToFile = false)
        {
            _richTextBox = richTextBox;
            this.saveToFile = saveToFile;
        }

        public void Log(string message, Color textColor)
        {
            if (_richTextBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                _richTextBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    LogInternal(message, textColor);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                LogInternal(message, textColor);
            }
        }

        private void LogInternal(string message, Color textColor)
        {
            _richTextBox.SelectionStart = _richTextBox.TextLength;
            _richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            _richTextBox.SelectionColor = textColor;
            _richTextBox.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
            _richTextBox.SelectionColor = _richTextBox.ForeColor;

            // Scroll to the caret (the end)
            _richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();

            if (saveToFile)
            {
                SaveToFile(message); // Save to a file if the flag is set
            }
        }

        private void SaveToFile(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                string folderName = "Logs"; // Replace with the desired folder name
                string fileName = "log.txt"; // Replace with the desired file name
                string logFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, folderName, fileName);

                // Ensure the directory exists, and create it if it doesn't
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, folderName));

                // Append the message to the log file
                File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions related to file I/O here
                Console.WriteLine("Error saving to log file: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried so far.

I added two more methods to save the richTExtBox1 Rtf content to a file and to load it back.  The problem is that it's loading back each time only the first saved part of the first time and even that the file have more content and I see it's getting to the save and load methods it keeps loading only the first saved part of the file and not all the content.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lightnings_Detector
{
    public class Logger
    {
        private readonly RichTextBox _richTextBox;
        private bool saveToFile; // Added a flag to indicate whether to save to a file
        private string logFilePath = "";
        private string rtbInfoFilePath = "";
        private RichTextBox _richTextBoxRtf;

        public Logger(RichTextBox richTextBox, bool saveToFile = false)
        {
            _richTextBoxRtf = new RichTextBox();

            _richTextBox = richTextBox;
            this.saveToFile = saveToFile;

            string folderName = "Logs"; // Replace with the desired folder name
            string fileName = "log.txt"; // Replace with the desired file name
            logFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, folderName, fileName);

            string rtbInfoFolder = "Logs";
            string rtbInfoFileName = "rtbinfo.txt";
            rtbInfoFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, rtbInfoFolder, rtbInfoFileName);

            // Ensure the directory exists, and create it if it doesn't
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, folderName));
        }

        public void Log(string message, Color textColor)
        {
            if (_richTextBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                _richTextBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    LogInternal(message, textColor);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                LogInternal(message, textColor);
            }
        }

        private void LogInternal(string message, Color textColor)
        {
            _richTextBox.SelectionStart = _richTextBox.TextLength;
            _richTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;
            _richTextBox.SelectionColor = textColor;
            _richTextBox.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
            _richTextBox.SelectionColor = _richTextBox.ForeColor;

            // Scroll to the caret (the end)
            _richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();

            if (saveToFile)
            {
                SaveToFile(message); // Save to a file if the flag is set
            }
        }

        private void SaveToFile(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                // Append the message to the log file
                File.AppendAllText(logFilePath, message + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions related to file I/O here
                Console.WriteLine("Error saving to log file: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }


        public void SaveRichtextboxRtfInfomation(RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(rtbInfoFilePath))
                {
                    File.Create(rtbInfoFilePath);
                    File.AppendAllText(rtbInfoFilePath, rtb.Rtf);
                }
                else
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(rtbInfoFilePath, rtb.Rtf);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error reading log file: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public string LoadRichtextboxRtfInfomation()
        {
            _richTextBoxRtf.Rtf = File.ReadAllText(rtbInfoFilePath);

            return _richTextBoxRtf.Rtf;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I'm using it.  in form1 constructor:

```
logger = new Logger(richTextBox1, checkBoxSaveLogger.Checked);
richTextBox1.Rtf = logger.LoadRichtextboxRtfInfomation();
```

and saving the Rtf content in two places in my code like this:

```
logger.SaveRichtextboxRtfInfomation(richTextBox1);
```

The saving part is working I can see the content of the file getting bigger size and more content the rtbinfo.txt file but when loading it back it's loading only the first part of the file and not all the file content.

Comment: Save the RichTextBox's RTF content. Maybe along with the plain text, if really necessary (probably not).

Comment: @Jimi I tried to go with the RTF content saving it and loading back.  first time saving and loading was fine but next times it's loading only the first part of the file even if it keep saving fine and keep adding content to the file rtbinfo.txt but when loading back it keep loading only the first part of the file and not all of it.  I edited my question added the code of what I have tried.

Comment: I don't see where, in your code, you're calling `SaveRichtextboxRtfInfomation()` (which should use `WriteAllText()`, not `AppendAllText()`). You're still calling `SaveToFile()` there (which won't work) -- Two note: the RichTextBox cannot hold much text, ot's not done for that. You should not use `Application.StartupPath` as the destination folder: when you deploy, if the application is installed in `Program Files` or similar, most probably you won't have write rights there

Comment: You could use `Application.CommonAppDataPath` or `Application.UserAppDataPath`. See what those point to, to decide which one is a better fit

Comment: @Jimi WriteAllText did the job.  but what did you mean by RichTextBox cannot hold much text ? then how do I make a logger?  with what control should I create a logger ?

Comment: Well, logging is not related to a GUI. If you need to show the log in real time, you should introduce some form of pagination. Anyway, see how it works in your context. You can also try [FastColoredTextBox](https://github.com/PavelTorgashov/FastColoredTextBox/tree/master), this is designed to handle a large amount of text. IIRC, the formatted text can be stored as a JSON, which is handier than RTF